# Adding BAF and Log2 ratio to VCF file

Tags: vcf, microarray, cnv

I have access to pre-processed VCF files from a genetic dataset, and am trying to use the MoChA tool to calculate mosaic chromosomal alterations in this dataset. However, MoChA requires BAF and log2ratio values for each of the variants, which are missing from the VCF files given, and the original genome array CEL files are unavailable so I cannot redo the variant calling and include these statistics

Instead, they have provided us with nexus format CNV files (from the [Axiom CNV summary tools](https://www.thermofisher.com/ca/en/home/life-science/microarray-analysis/microarray-analysis-instruments-software-services/microarray-analysis-software/axiom-cnv-summary-tools-software.html)) for each of the samples with a host of log2 ratio and BAF files across the different Axiom probes.

I am just a bit confused about how we can use these files to import the BAF and log2ratio values into the VCF for MoChA. Any suggestions?

A couple sample rows of the CNV file are included here (I've removed the sample identifier and replaced with ---).

```
Sample  ProbeSetName    Chromosome      Position        Log2Ratio       BAF
---     AFFX-KIT-000001 9       101258881       -0.440535940556599      0.482727669963674
---     AFFX-KIT-000002 4       164934874       -0.106227164241716      0.057035393165642
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. The manual from GitHub https://github.com/freeseek/mocha appears to describe this in detail both for BAF and log2 (which the manual calls LRR for Log R Ratio). I would recommend reading the manual because it is extensive and looks very clear.